# How to Click one button and active 2 buttons in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello im at coding a multi-step form and my jquery script split my form in different sections with the fieldset tag so all and good.

I need somehow a code that if a click over a button to activate the same time the other button that is hidden , Hidden because as i mention jquery split my form in different sections so for example:

If /fieldset tag than fieldset> the other other form start, and my forms have headers and footers tag inside them so  if i click over the next button and the button is placed inside the footer tag it changes just the footer container

So if i put another button inside the fieldset and push there next it work just i want but i want the button to be placesd in the footer for aesthetic aspect so .

The ieda was to hide the button inside fieldset tag and link it with the button inside the footer tag any idea  here is my code thanks in advance!

```
      <section1>
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="copy"><i></i><strong>Send a copy to my e-mail address</strong></label>
</section1>

<input type='button' name="Next" class='next action-button' value='Próximo' />
 <div class="row">
    <header1>
        <input type='button' name='Next' class='next action-button' value='Próximo' />
    </header1>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

script : in this link look at the js section : http://codepen.io/pedroG/pen/hKarC

i tried this `

```
</section1>
    <input type="button" class='hidden_button' style='display:none'  value="Próximo" />
       <div class="row">
                    <header1>
  <input type="button" name="Next" id='button1' class="next action-button "  value="Próximo"/>
                    </header1>
<script type="text/javascript">                     
$('#button1').click(function()
{ 
 $('.hidden_button').show();
});</script>

but still with no success`
```

Comment: Um... where's your script?

Comment: Can you please reword the question and break it into sentences?  I don't think I can follow your thoughts otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Give them both an ID and use jQuery's click function.

`$('#button1').click(function(){ $('#button2').click() });`

Answer (score 0):

Give the both a class and not an id because the is for one element and not more ,so we make :

```
<input type='button' id='button1' />
<input type='hidden' class='hidden_button' />
<input type='hidden' class='hidden_button' />
$('#button1').click(function()
{ 
 $('.hidden_button').attr('type','button');
});
```

or this code :

```
<input type='button' id='button1' />
<input type='button' class='hidden_button' style='display:none'/>
 <input type='button' class='hidden_button' style='display:none'/>

$('#button1').click(function()
{ 
 $('.hidden_button').show();

});
```

Comment: i cant bring the jquery script to work somehow haha :S

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to change your jquery so that your form is not split up but if that isn't an option you could use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#mainButton").click(function(){
        $( "#button2" ).click();
        $( "#button3" ).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: im a noob in jquery :S

Comment: @Flamur ok, that works by waiting for a button with the id of "mainButton" to be clicked and when it is it runs the function which clicks the 2 buttons in there button2 and button3 both have that as an id

Answer (score 0):

One click  clicking two buttons in same time :

Html:

```
<input type="button" name="Next" id='button2' class="next action-button " value="Próximo" />
        <div class="row">
                    <header1>
        <input type="button" name='Next' id='button1'   class='next action-button '  value='Próximo' />
        </header1>
      </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#button1').click(function(){ $('#button2').click() });</script>
```

Thanks to all the guys who helped me .